# django - Missing fields in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to get the `pub_date` and the `update` option in the admin. But there's no such thing. In the admin there's only field for `username`, `password` and `client ip`. What am I missing? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username


class IP(models.Model):
    client_ip = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

*Update:*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Member, IP
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Member)
admin.site.register(IP)
```

Comment: Show the `ModelAdmin` code for this model, please.

Comment: @catavaran I have updated, please have a look.

Comment: Remove `auto_now` arguments and only leave the `auto_now_add`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is read-only field, so it is ignored by default in Django Admin. To show it, you have to define custom `ModelAdmin` class and specify it in `fields` atribute.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Member, IP

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'pub_date', 'update')

class IPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('client_ip', 'pub_date', 'update')

admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
admin.site.register(IP, IPAdmin)
```

You can use `fieldsets` instead of `fields` to display fields in more sections ([click](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)).

I'm not aware of any options where you don't have to specify all fields to display.

PS: You can omit `auto_now_add = False` and `auto_now = False` as they are set to `False` by default.

Answer (score 1):

@Selcuk is right, there is not much sense of editing the automatic fields, so django excludes datetime fields with `auto_now*` arguments from the admin.

If you really want to see these fields in admin then you have to change the model to mimic the `auto_now*` behavior:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Member(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    update = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.pub_date = timezone.now()
        else:
            kwargs['update_fields'] = ['username', 'password', 'update']
        self.update = timezone.now()
        return super(Member, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But note that if you will try to edit the fields your changes will be ignored.